# How to create query string with a map in it? (Java)

Tags: java, python, apache-commons-httpclient

I need to call this service in Java -

```
https://api.semantics3.com/test/v1/products?q={"cat_id": "13658", "brand": "Toshiba", "model": "Satellite"}
```

I've managed to do this in python as follows -

```
class Semantics:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.service_address = 'https://api.semantics3.com/test/v1/products?'
        self.api_key = 'SEM3158A71D4AB3A3715C2230B96943F46D0'
    def query(self, params):
        query = 'q=' + params.__dict__.__str__().replace("'",'"')
        query = urlencode(urlparse.parse_qs(query), True)
        req = Request(url = self.service_address + query)
        req.add_header('api_key', self.api_key)        
        return urlopen(req).read()

class QueryParams:
    def __init__(self, cat_id, model, brand):
        self.cat_id = cat_id
        self.model = model
        self.brand = brand

qp = QueryParams('13658', 'Satellite', "Toshiba")
print Semantics().query(qp)
```

I have tried writing an equivalent Java program using `Spring REST API` and `Apache HttpClient` to no avail. I can't find a way to set a dictionary (i.e. Map) into the query String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String uri = "https://api.semantics3.com/test/v1/products?";

    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(uri);

    method.getParams().setParameter("q", "Toshiba");//How do I insert a Map here?

    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER,
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

    method.setRequestHeader("api_key", "SEM2158A71D4AB3A3715C2435B96943F46D0");     
    try {
        int statusCode = hc.executeMethod(method);
        System.out.println(statusCode);
        byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
        System.out.println(new String(responseBody));
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        method.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

**At the lowest level I can manually produce the query string manually via concatenation and then Url encode it. But is there a more elegant way to do it?**

Comment: The format of you q is JSON, why don't you use a JSON Lib to get your values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use external jar like [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to convert the `Map` into JSON

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("cat_id", "12345");
```

..

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
method.getParams().setParameter("q", gson.toJson(map));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Google's Http Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/)

As you can see from the [examples](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/dailymotion-simple-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/dailymotion/cmdline/simple/DailyMotionSample.java?repo=samples&r=e65ea72cccf1ee0f6eb354b6cf50a78e5ef8384e), it uses objects to build the request url and deserialise the response body. [The docs](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON) also show you how to deserialise JSON specifically, and you can choose your JSON library of choice.